$0 Stripe Subscriptions
Has anyone successfully figured out how to do a $0 stripe subscription on commerce? Works fine in stripe but the commerce plugin requires a payment source and errors if you provide the payment source fields along with the $0 signup
If you have a payment source (plan swapping) it goes through fine with no payment source fields.
the error is craft\commerce\stripe\errors\PaymentSourceException: No payment sources are saved to use for subscriptions. and Im guessing its because Stripe doesnt make the payment source for a $0 transaction and so there's a check failing after that?
